# Status of all Evaluators?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, parallelization, kernel, monitoring

Since I have 4 cores on my machine I typically have 4 notebooks open each with their own kernel evaluator. I'd like to construct a dynamic pane similar to the parallel kernels status window:

[image]

But that collects a few statistics of all them:

- evaluation queue size
- cpu/gpu memory in use over time
- virtual memory in use
- uptime
- status

Here's how I get the names of the ones in use, but I'm unsure of how to query for further details:

```
n = Notebooks[]
Union[CurrentValue[#, "Evaluator"] & /@ n]
```

[image]

Comment: Much of the desired information is available from TaskManager on Windows, and I imagine that MAC OS has a similar program.  The question, then, is how to capture that information periodically and display it in a Mathematic table.  Here are two links [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process) [2](http://superuser.com/questions/209555/whats-the-easiest-way-to-save-task-managers-processes-tab-as-a-csv-file) that may provide hints, although they do not solve the problem.

Comment: By the way, if you obtain an answer, please publish it.  Good question (+1).

Comment: Note that this is likely going to have to be an FE process. I don't think the kernels track each other.